# Intercept all webjob method/function calls

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Is there a way to intercept a WebJob function call? I'd like to wrap it once rather than littering my code base (a dozen projects and hundreds of triggers) with repeated code to analyze the function call.

I'm familiar with `IJobActivator`, and am looking for something similar with regards to intercepting a method/function call.

Comment: Are you using any IoC Container in particular? Many of them have interceptor capabilites. I've implemented this using Ninject if it helps.

Comment: @lopezbertoni do you have any examples of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to intercept a WebJob function call?

You could use **Function Filters** which allow you to encapsulate common logic to be shared across many different functions.

Currently it supports two filter type: **Invocation Filters** and **Exception Filters**.

The Invocation Filters have both `Executing` and `Executed` methods that are called immediately before and immediately after the target job function is invoked.

You could apply filters globally by adding filters to the **JobHostConfiguration** service collection with following code:

```
var extensions = config.GetService<IExtensionRegistry>();
extensions.RegisterExtension<IFunctionInvocationFilter>(myFilter);
```

For more details, you could read this [wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Function-Filters) to learn.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed what I'm looking for.